# Serve dynamic content with Firebase Hosting/Functions in EU

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I would like to serve a Next.js app in europe using Firebase Hosting & Functions capabilities.

I do understand from the doc that:

> If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for Firebase
> Hosting, you must use us-central1

and that

> Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only

It's pretty clear: **you must use us-central**. But my main target is Europe..

I've read the following on the Cloud Functions locations guide:

> For HTTP and callable functions, we recommend that you first set your
> function to the destination region, or closest to where most expected
> customers are located, and then alter your original function to
> redirect its HTTP request to the new function (they can have the same
> name). `[Solution 1]` If clients of your HTTP function support
> redirects, you can simply change your original function to return an
> HTTP redirect status (301) along with the URL of your new function.
> `[Solution 2]` If your clients do not handle redirects well, you can
> proxy the request from the original function to the new function by
> initiating a new request from the original function to the new
> function. The final step is to ensure that all clients are calling the
> new function.

I've highlighted what seems to be two solutions to my initial problem:

**Solution 1**

- Have a us-central1 function that send a 301 redirection to https://europe-west1-[myProject].cloudfunctions.net/[myEuropeanFunction]
- Have a europe-west1 function that does the job (in my case, serve the Next.js app)
- Happily using Firestore located in europe-west1

This would only work if clients of the HTTP function support redirects. In my case, it's fine: all browsers support redirection.

```js
exports.nextServer = functions
    .https
    .onRequest((req, res) => {
        res.set('location', 'https://europe-west1-<my-project>.cloudfunctions.net/nextServerEurope');
        res.status(301).send()
    });

exports.nextServerEurope = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .https
    .onRequest((req, res) => {
        return server.prepare().then(() => nextjsHandle(req, res));
    });
```

The issue with that solution is that the URL changes in the browser to https://europe-west1-.cloudfunctions.net/nextServerEurope :-/

**Solution 2**

- Have a us-central1 function that initiate a new/proxy request to the europe-west1 function
- Have the same europe-west1 function that does the job (in my case, serve the Next.js app)
- Still happily using Firestore located in europe-west1

By proxy request (as suggested in the guide), it would mean using a lib like axios I suppose. I know there are some libraries to perform proxy request available for node as well.

However, with that solution, the first issue I can think of is the unnecessary delay introcuded by passing by the us endpoint:

`client -> us endpoint -> eu endpoint -> do stuff -> us endpoint -> client`

---

Billing wise, I'm wondering what would be the impact..

I know that two services from different regions calling each others can increase the latency and the billing (egress).

With the first solution, there's no egress traffic as it's only a redirection to the european endpoint. But the redirection itself is not a valid solution in my case.

It's unclear for me what would be the additional billing cost with the second solution (beside the latency cost): is the traffic for the proxy request from us to eu going to be expensive?

---

To wrap-up:

- The solution 1 is easy but leads to a non-transparent redirection
- The solution 2 seems ok but it requires extra http request which leads to extra-latency (and potentially extra billing)
  In the end, both solutions doesn't seem quite okay.

Therefore my question:

**How do you serve in Europe dynamic content using Firebase Hosting and Functions?**

Comment: Did you actually try anything you proposed here?  I suspect they won't work the way you expect, for various reasons.  I suggest that you don't use Cloud Functions at all.  Use Cloud Run instead.

Comment: Yes, I did. The first solution is not viable (as explained). The second solution is just wrong architecture-wise (I'm not an expert, but having to put a proxy request to bypass a limitation seems wrong to me). You can find many tutorials about deploying Next.js on Cloud Functions, therefore my question. But in the end, with such a limitation, it seems it only applies to the US audience. A bit surprised/puzzled by this limitation.. That's all. I'll check Cloud Run. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting only supports Cloud Functions in Us-Central as you mentioned and as stated in the [Firebase Hosting Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#connect_functions_to_hosting).

I have created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/175766484) in Public Issue Tracker to support other regions when using Firebase Hosting with Cloud Functions. Please note, there is no ETA when this will be implemented.

So as @Doug Stevenson suggest, you can use [Firebase Hosting with Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) instead to serve your Dynamic Content.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll be glad to support this feature request if it works like that (although I'm not able to access the link you provided)

Comment: When accessing to the Feature Request in Public Issue Tracker, does it give you any error or something?

Comment: Yes: "Access denied for: xxx@gmail.com". Strangely enough, when I visit https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/ I get a full list of bug/features request and I can click on them to see the details (like this random one https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175796493)

Comment: Now you should be able to see the Feature Request as now it is Public. Please try again to access it.

Comment: Please note, this feature will only work with the updated Firebase CLI as several deployment changes were made

Answer (score 2):

Just to update. As of August 2022.

Finally, latency issue can be solved easily for now.

> Firebase Hosting rewrites to CF3 are able to be done to any CF3
> region, not just us-central1.

Reference: [Feature Request Ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175766484#comment19)